# SQL Query to create a report of matches played

Tags: sql

Recently I have been asked a below SQL query question? Can someone help me with this one. I have a table with three columns - Home Team, Away Team, and Winner Team. Like given below.

```
H_T  A_T  W_T
AUS  IND  IND
ENG  AUS  ENG
IND  AUS  AUS
AUS  ENG  AUS
ENG  IND  IND
IND  ENG  IND
```

Above data needs to be converted in SQL to show the report with below attributes
Team Name, Total Matches Played, Win Count, Draw Count, Loss Count, Points.

To calculate points, these are the formulas for each kind (win/draw/loss)

Win = Win Count * 3

Draw = Draw Count * 1

Loss = Loss Count * 0

Point will be summed up with above three values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What determines a draw?  And which database are you using?

Comment: Add the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: You can do it with group by and aggregate functions like sum. Also which db provider are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Need a little more information as to what defines a `draw`, this assumes the `w_t` column contains the value `draw` instead of a team.

Either way, you can use `conditional aggregation` to get your desired results.  Normally you would have a `teams` table and `join` to it, but you can create that with a `union` and a subquery:

```
select t.*, 
  (win_count * 3) + (draw_count) as Points
from (
  select t.team,
    count(*) Total_Matches_Played,
    count(case when t.team = y.w_t then 1 end) Win_Count,
    count(case when t.team <> y.w_t then 1 end) Loss_Count,
    count(case when y.w_t = 'DRAW' then 1 end) Draw_Count
  from (
    select h_t as team from yourtable
    union select a_t from yourtable
    ) t join yourtable y on t.team in (y.a_t,y.h_t)
  group by t.team
  ) t
```

Comment: Just a note, ANSI SQL requires `t.*` instead of `*` in the select list. (`*` must be all alone.)